# Regex: exclude string from matched pattern

Tags: regex

Input string:

`hrStorageDescr{hrStorageDescr="devfs: dev file system, mounted on: /.mount/dev"}`

Regex to match value of `hrStorageDescr` only:

`.*hrStorageDescr="(.*?)",.*`

How to write this regex in order to preserve matching function, but exclude everything in the value, if `devfs` string is matched?

Comment: Do you means like this? `.*?hrStorageDescr="(?!devfs)([^"]+)"` https://regex101.com/r/4thX83/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match *bhrStorageDescr* preceded by a word boundary `\b`

First match *="* and assert what is directly to the right is not *devfs* followed by a word boundary using a negative lookahead `(?!devfs\b)`

If that assertion succeeds, capture in the group matching any char except a `"` using a negated character class and close the group before matching the closing double quote `([^"]+)`

Using `.*` will match the last occurrence of the pattern, using `.*?` will match the first. If you want to match all occurrences you could omit that part, assuming you allowed to match all matches instead of a single match.

```
.*?\bhrStorageDescr="(?!devfs\b)([^"]+)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4thX83/1)